# How can I delete one row in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have this code:

```
1441149726 jezevec Lukas
1441173967 tesak Petr
1441174056 kuna Marek
1441174063 myval Lukas
14411728 potter Marek
1441175214 hermiona Marek
1441219281 liska Marek
1441219282 liska Marek
1441219282 liska Marek
1441219283 liska Marek
```

How Can I delete first record with liska on 7th line? Maybe with sed? I have it in a file.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/liska/{/liska/d}' file
```

Output:

```
1441149726 jezevec Lukas
1441173967 tesak Petr
1441174056 kuna Marek
1441174063 myval Lukas
14411728 potter Marek
1441175214 hermiona Marek
1441219282 liska Marek
1441219282 liska Marek
1441219283 liska Marek
```

Comment: Cute. I hadn't thought of using the first match as part of a range definition.

Answer (score 1):

A short `awk` script is one approach that offers substantial control:

```
awk '
BEGIN { seen=0; }
{
  if(seen == 0 && $2 == "liska") {
    seen=1
  } else {
    print $0
  }
}
' <infile >outfile
```

That said, you could literally implement this in native bash, too, if you wanted:

```
#!/bin/bash

seen=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if ((seen == 0)) && [[ $line = *" liska *" ]]; then
    seen=1
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done <in.txt >out.txt
mv out.txt in.txt # if you want to replace the input file
```